# Referring category link on single product pages with multiple categories | Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am literally at my wits end. I'm so sorry for all the questions.

I have a site with thousands of products on it. Each of these products might belong to multiple categories. I would like to enable a link that will take a user back to the referring category. Breadcrumbs work, only to go to the main category, I need them to go back to the category they clicked through from.

Previous page js doesn't work as i've enabled infinite scrolling and it takes me to the page i was at, but will not allow me to scroll to the top.

I have tried so many ways to accomplish this and just can't find one that works.

I am using flatsome theme.

Comment: How about saving the previous URL to a cookie?

Comment: that's a good idea, but won't that simply take me back to the push state page in the infinite scrolling rather than the actual category page itself?

The issue is that using previous takes me to the pushstate page and not the category page and the user cannot scroll up. So if i was on page 3 it takes me back to page 3 but does not allow me to scroll back up to the top of the page.

Also you rock for trying to help x

Comment: you can test it out, by writing the URL you want to visit - I would be surprised if it would scroll you down to the earlier state? when saving the link, and click on a href to it - you shouldn't use any push states since it will be a new refferer? -- Not sure, test it out :)